# Is there a way to download an offline copy of the Stack Overflow questions?

Tags: support

Is there a way to download an offline copy of the Stack Overflow questions? I am hoping I can view it offline.

Thanks guys. I have found the cc-wiki-dump for Stack Overflow.

But the post in the dump XML file looks like below. I don't know where the category tag is. For example, the category tag for this question is "support".

[image]

### ADD 1 - 11:22 AM 11/9/2018

I made a StackExchangeArchiver, and it can archive questions/answers of a specific user into a pure HTML offline page, including the images. It's made in a haste. But it can work. It's open-sourced here:https://github.com/smwikipedia/StackExchangeArchiver

I hope it can be helpful to other people.

Comment: http://stackprinter.com

Comment: You can also have fun with an offline copy in the [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com) aka SEDE.

Comment: The tags appear as attribute called "Tags" in the "row" element.

Comment: OMG...I think i need some rest. Didn't know how I missed that...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[archive.org](http://archive.org) hosts archives of every Stack Exchange website since January 2014: [Stack Exchange Data Dump](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange).

> This is an anonymized dump of all user-contributed content on the Stack Exchange network. Each site is formatted as a separate archive consisting of XML files zipped via 7-zip using bzip2 compression. Each site archive includes Posts, Users, Votes, Comments, PostHistory and PostLinks. For complete schema information, see the included readme.txt.

But, be aware that the [posts archive of Stack Overflow](https://archive.org/download/stackexchange/stackoverflow.com-Posts.7z) takes 14GB, have fun downloading it :-) See the [official blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/01/stack-exchange-cc-data-now-hosted-by-the-internet-archive/) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I need. But I just checked the xml file. I want to find the category tags for the question. But no luck so far.

Comment: For the record, now (2018-10-19 13:00) 12.4GB.

Comment: 14GB in 2019...

Comment: "every Stack Exchange" Well, minus a few.

Comment: @Mast yes, e.g.  [Why does the closed beta site "Big Data" have no data dump available?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/267415/178179)

Comment: The dumps don't contain images. Images can be downloaded [here](https://github.com/Franck-Dernoncourt/Stack-Exchange-Image-Dataset).