# Why does the closed beta site "Big Data" have no data dump available?

Tags: discussion, data-dump, private-beta, closed-sites

I wonder why the closed beta site [Big Data](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/40518) has no data dump available.

Comment: May have been too big.

Comment: I think it used to be that private beta sites wouldn't have data dumps published, since the content was only accessible to those who'd originally committed to the site.

Comment: Related: [What happens to the content of a SE site that has been closed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/379982/289691)

Comment: Can the close voters please elaborate on what additional detail is required? Almost all site proposals on Area 51 for sites that are later closed have a link to download a data dump for the site. It's extremely unusual for a closed site proposal to not have a link to download its data dump; this question is asking why it's not present for this specific proposal.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In all likelihood: it was forgotten.

It was explicitly pointed out that Big Data needed a dump made internally, but it wasn't integrated into the process at that point and it just never got done. Now, it can't because the data doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: Going through Area 51, [Relationships and Dating](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/44577/relationships-and-dating) and the [first iteration of Machine Learning](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/26434/machine-learning) also don't have data dumps published (and are the only two others that don't). Is it the same scenario for those two sites?

Comment: Big Data site, with no data at all. Quite the irony.